# Infinite scrolling background with transform, how to get rid of snap of animation?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with background image and I want to make effect of infinite scrolling.

I'm trying to do it with transform. The problem which I am facing is the when the animation reach a certain point (I guess when width of `bg` div is reached with `transform`) the animation snaps back to the beginning of the image.

Is there a way to avoid this issue?

As reference I used [this article](https://css-tricks.com/books/volume-i/infinite-scrolling-background-image/)

HTML

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.holder {
    height: 60%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40%;
    left: 0;
}
.bg {
    background-image: url('bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 22416px; // width of image 3 times
    height: 70%;
    transform: translateZ(1px);
    animation: slide 60s linear infinite;
}
```

My animation

```
@keyframes slide{
  0%{
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate3d(-7472px, 0, 0); // width of image
  }
}
```

Comment: Trying this out here: https://codepen.io/mkstix6/pen/JmwGZG – sometimes still seeing a white flash.

Comment: @MarkStickling Thanks! This is works pretty good. The only problem is specifing background size. It strech image because I have height of div speciefied.

Comment: I've updated the codepen with a couple of Scss variables for background image width and height. You could try tweaking these values to suit your image. Sorry if you're not familiar with Scss. In CodePen you can view the compiled CSS using the dropdown in the top-right-corner of the CSS area.

Comment: @MarkStickling I'm familiar with Scss, thank you, your solution really helped me.